# Run Android Activity from c# code(I use Xamarin with Monogame)

Tags: c#, android, android-activity, xamarin, monogame

I use Xamarin with Monogame and i need run android activity from c# code. I try do this:

```
public class Test : Activity

{

public void Start()
{
  StartActivity(typeof(MyActivity));
}

}

}
```

Then from Update() i calling Start().

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{ 
   ...
   Test test = new Test();
   test.Start();
   ...
}
```

But i have error.
Help me, please

Comment: Post the complete error message that you are recieving.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An existing `Activity` instance has a bit of work that goes on behind the scenes when it's constructed; activities started through the intent system (all activities) will have a `Context` reference added to them when they are instantiated. This context reference is used in the call-chain of `StartActivity`.

So, the `Java.Lang.NullPointerException` seen after invoking `StartActivity` on your `Test` activity instance is because the `Context` inside that instance has never been set. By using the `new` operator to create an activity instance you've circumvented the *normal* way activities are instantiated, leaving your instance in an invalid state!

This can be fixed by using the global application context to launch the activity:

```
var intent = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(Test));
intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity (intent);
```

Comment: Thanks. I have thought it impossible)