# Getting Java.Lang.NullPointerException when trying to open GPS Settings page using Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, gps, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am getting the following error when trying to open GPS settings page if GPS is not enabled (within Xamarin):

> Unknown identifier: StartActivity
>
> Unhandled Exception:
>
> Java.Lang.NullPointerException:

Can somebody please guide where am I getting wrong?

This My Interface

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public interface GpsSettings
    {
        void showGpsSettings();
    }
}
```

This the Implementation

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(GpsSettingsImplementation))]
namespace MyApp.Droid
{

    public class GpsSettingsImplementation : Activity, GpsSettings
    {
        public GpsSettingsImplementation()
        {

        }


        public void showGpsSettings()
        {

            var intent = new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionLocationSourceSettings);
            StartActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I call my function on button click

```
 DependencyService.Get<GpsSettings>().showGpsSettings();
```

Comment: Have you checked the Android project Properties - Android Manifest? 

You may be missing a required permission. I think you need ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION.

Comment: @Musters These permissions are already there

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="MyApp.MyApp" android:installLocation="internalOnly" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />`

Comment: it shows `Unknown identifier: StartActivity`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> An existing Activity instance has a bit of work that goes on behind
>   the scenes when it's constructed; activities started through the
>   intent system (all activities) will have a Context reference added to
>   them when they are instantiated. This context reference is used in the
>   call-chain of StartActivity.
>
> So, the Java.Lang.NullPointerException seen after invoking
>   StartActivity on your Test activity instance is because the Context
>   inside that instance has never been set. By using the new operator to
>   create an activity instance you've circumvented the normal way
>   activities are instantiated, leaving your instance in an invalid
>   state!

*ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31330999/5145530*

The above error can be resolved in the following manner:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(GpsSettingsImplementation))]
namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    public class GpsSettingsImplementation : Activity, GpsSettings
    {
        public GpsSettingsImplementation()
        {

        }


        public void showGpsSettings()
        {

            var intent = new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionLocationSourceSettings);
            intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);

        }
    }
}
```